# Не выводит текст в файл

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

```
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    int s;

    String^ fileName = "textfile.txt";
    StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(fileName);
    sw->WriteLine("A text file is born!");

    String^ S1 = textBox1->Text;
    s = Convert::ToInt32(S1);
    s = s * 0.9;
    textBox2->Text = s.ToString();
}
```

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку считает, а в файл нечего не записывается искал много способов записи в файл, ругался на все кроме этого.
cli c++

Answer (score 1):

Запись в текстовый файл

Этот пример кода использует класс `StreamWriter` для создания и записи в файл. Если имеется существующий файл, можно открыть его таким же образом.

```
StreamWriter* pwriter = new StreamWriter(S"c:\\KBTest.txt");
pwriter->WriteLine(S"File created using StreamWriter class.");
pwriter->Close();
listBox1->Items->Clear();
String *filew = gcnew String(S"File Written to C:\\KBTest.txt");
listBox1->Items->Add(filew);
```

Читайте [документацию](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/307398/how-to-do-basic-file-i-o-in-visual-c-or-in-visual-c-net) по работе с файлами в visual c++

Comment: если просто добавить listBox1 на форму он будет ругаться на код.
не допускается использовать обычные указатели на классы ссылок или классы интерфейсов C++/CLI.
оператор new нельзя применять к классам управляемый (вместо него следует использовать gcnew)

Comment: @mangyst Привел вам в ответе пример записи в файл из документации. Я не думаю, что на сайте Microsoft есть критические ошибки в коде.

Comment: @Kinstantin_SH там код для старых версий в новой по другому, нашел на этом же сайте, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
    StreamWriter^ pwriter = gcnew StreamWriter("Test.txt");         
    pwriter->WriteLine(s.ToString());  //вывод переменной s
    pwriter->Close();
```

Так работает в Visual Studio 2019, mvc142.